# How to use 2 interfaces to describe any array that return 2 different types of results

Tags: typescript

I have this code down below I want instead of using any I want to describe the 2 different values using the interface the problem here is it is not working can I use 2 interfaces as union type? if not how to describe the output of this (set) variable then?

```js
interface Arr {
  [index: string]: [
    {
      id: string;
      name: string;
    }
  ];
}

interface Obj {
  [index: string]: {
    [index: string]: [
      {
        id: string;
        name: string;
      }
    ];
  };
}


  const set : Arr | Obj = { ItemsArr: context.ItemsArr['ItmesArr'], ItemsObj: context.ItemsObj['ItmesObj'] };
```

Comment: You can do a single interface that has ItemsArr and ItemsObj interface

Comment: Do you want a `type MySet = { ItemsArr: Arr, ItemsObj: Obj}` to represent the `set` variable?

Comment: @MeritonReqica can you show this dual interface? as an answer

Comment: You can check it here if this is what you need : 
https://jsfiddle.net/t4Leqsbn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```ts
interface ItemInterface {
  ItemsArr : Arr,
  ItemsObj : Obj
}

interface Arr {
  [index: string]: [
    {
      id: string;
      name: string;
    }
  ];
}

interface Obj {
  [index: string]: {
    [index: string]: [
      {
        id: string;
        name: string;
      }
    ];
  };
}


  const set : ItemInterface = { ItemsArr: context?.ItemsArr['ItmesArr'], ItemsObj: context?.ItemsObj['ItmesObj'] };
```